# Angular Material Autocomplete default filter not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm using the Autocomplete component from Angular Material, which works, with the exception of the searching filter (which is the default one from the example), which won't search based on my input, only displaying all the elements when I begin typing.

HTML:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="pacientForm">
    <label class="example-radio-group">Disease</label>
              <input type="text"
               matInput
               [(ngModel)]="pacient.disease"
               formControlName="disease"
               [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredDiseaseOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```
pacientForm: FormGroup = new PacientCreateFormBuilder().build();
pacient: Pacient;
diseaseOptions: string[] = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
filteredDiseaseOptions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredDiseaseOptions = this.pacientForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.diseaseOptions.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

FormGroup:

```
export class PacientCreateFormBuilder {

  public build(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      disease: new FormControl('', []),
    });
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `this.filteredDiseaseOptions = this.pacientForm.get('disease').valueChanges()`.

`disease` is the form control name you want to subscribe to.

Comment: It's not working and it gets an error since the expression is not callable using this way. I've tried instead this.filteredDiseaseOptions = this.pacientForm.value.disease.valueChanges(); but the dropdown won't open anymore.

Comment: try `this.pacientForm.value.disease.valueChanges().pipe(map(val => consol.log(val)))` and see any value printing when input.

Comment: The console prints undefined, since the operation is used on component's init.

Comment: you are not connected to the input field, normally this is how yo do `this.pacientForm.get('disease').valueChanges()`. in your case you are building fromgroup from another class. i am not sure how to reach the input.

Comment: Actually using this.filteredDiseaseOptions = this.pacientForm.get('disease').valueChanges runs, but the filter is still not working.